# Nested View not getting data from parent controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm building an Employee Management system and The employee part works good but when i try to create for family members for an employee i have a problem. 
I was hoping i can create a family member for an employee in such a way 
localhost/mysite/employees/5/families/create

Here are my files
P.S - I have omitted some of the code which i thought was irrelevant. For example, there are more than 30 employee fields that i save. For this question i just displayed the FirstName

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');
Route::resource('employees.families', 'FamiliesController');
```

**EmployeesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class EmployeesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {              
        //Stuff that works well on employees/index
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //Stuff that works well on employees/create
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Stuff that works well     
    }


    public function show(Employee $employee)
    {
        $employee=Employee::find($EmployeeID);
        return view('employees.show', compact('employee'));
    }


    public function edit($EmployeeID)
    {
        $employee=Employee::find($EmployeeID);          
        return view('employees.edit',compact('employee'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $EmployeeID)
    {
         //Stuff that works well on employees/edit
    }

}
```

**Employee.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'EmployeeID';

    protected $fillable=[
        'Name'
    ];

    public function families()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Family');
    }
}
```

**FamilyController.php (For now i only posted the index and create methods)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Employee;
use App\Family;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FamiliesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Employee $employee)
    {
        return view('families.index', compact('employee'));
    }

    public function create(Employee $employee)
    {
        return view('families.create', compact('employee'));
    }

}
```

**Family.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Family extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

      protected $primaryKey = 'FamilyID';

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

**Result from php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                            | Name                       | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | employees                                      | employees.index            | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@index   |            |
|        | POST     | employees                                      | employees.store            | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@store   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/create                               | employees.create           | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@create  |            |
|        | PATCH    | employees/{employees}                          |                            | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@update  |            |
|        | PUT      | employees/{employees}                          | employees.update           | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@update  |            |
|        | DELETE   | employees/{employees}                          | employees.destroy          | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@destroy |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}                          | employees.show             | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@show    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}/edit                     | employees.edit             | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@edit    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}/families                 | employees.families.index   | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@index    |            |
|        | POST     | employees/{employees}/families                 | employees.families.store   | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@store    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}/families/create          | employees.families.create  | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@create   |            |
|        | PUT      | employees/{employees}/families/{families}      | employees.families.update  | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@update   |            |
|        | DELETE   | employees/{employees}/families/{families}      | employees.families.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@destroy  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}/families/{families}      | employees.families.show    | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@show     |            |
|        | PATCH    | employees/{employees}/families/{families}      |                            | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@update   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{employees}/families/{families}/edit | employees.families.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\FamiliesController@edit     |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | employees/{id}/delete                          |                            | App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController@delete  |            |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

When i navigate to http://localhost/mysite/public/employees/1/families/create i can see the create form but it's not getting the employee data. i did a vardump of $employee on that page and i was expecting to see the data for EmployeeID = 1 (as you can see from the url), but it was blank. Funny thing is that it's not throwing an error, it receives the $employee data passed from the controller but it a blank data.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using route model binding? If so, can you post that code? If you aren't, then your code will naturally return an empty instance of Employee. Laravel will automatically try to inject instances of the arguments in your methods, but in order for it to fetch a specific Employee, you still have to let it know how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create method on the **familiescontroller.php** isn't getting which Employee we are using. The following is how the create method is supposed to be on

```
 public function create($EmployeeID)
    {
        $employee = Employee::findOrFail($EmployeeID);
        return view('families.create')->with('employee', $employee);
    }
```